# getting asynchronous behavior inside success function during ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, frontend

I have written a function to execute loader in my hyperlink which is working fine in chrome but not in IE.

`function displayUserRequest(isLoginPage) {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url :  ......
        dataType : 'html',
        beforeSend: function() {
            startLoader();
        },
        success : function(macResponse) {
            $('.modal-content').empty();
            $('.modal-content').html(macResponse);
            stopLoader();
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("error:" + e);
            stopLoader();
        },
    });
}`

startLoader and stopLoader are function for displaying and to stop loader.
 Above code is working fine i.e startLoader start before response and stop as    soon as page is loaded in chrome but not in IE.

### IE Issue

loader was not working at all .i thought  it is not calling startLoader()   function  but after commenting stopLoader() function its working
  fine but there was nothing to stop the loader (obviously I don't want this).

As i am new to javascript any help would be appreciated . Thanks in Advance

```
function startLoader(){
var $div = $('div.loaderModal');
if(undefined != $div){
    $div.remove();
}
$( "body" ).append("<div class='loaderModal' style='display: none'><div class='loaderCenter'><img alt='' src='/clr/img/loader.gif' /> </div></div>");
$(".loaderModal").show();
}'


function stopLoader(){
$(".loaderModal").hide();
}
```

Comment: Can you make an example. Your provided code should work fine, so there should be a problem somewhere in the code which we don't have.

Comment: Post code for `startLoader` and `stopLoader`.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have edited my question.